# Как разрешить подключение по ssh только с адресов, разных для каждого пользователя

Tags: ssh

Нужно разрешить подключение по ssh одному пользователю с одного набора адресов, другому пользователю с другого набора адресов.

iptables и firewall тут не подходит.

Comment: https://yurisk.info/2011/04/05/two-tips-to-secure-ssh-access-from-specific-ips-to-specific-users-in-checkpoint-or-any-linux/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, @Mike.

Приведу в виде ответа:

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
AllowUsers admin@123.123.123.10 admin@10.88.88.* pupkin@1.2.3.4 yurisk
```

- `admin` может подключаться с адресов 123.123.123.123 или 10.88.88.0/24
- `pupkin` может подключаться с адреса 1.2.3.4
- `yurisk` может подключаться откуда угодно

После правок `sshd_config` сервис `sshd` должен быть перезапущен.

[Статья с исходной информацией](https://yurisk.info/2011/04/05/two-tips-to-secure-ssh-access-from-specific-ips-to-specific-users-in-checkpoint-or-any-linux/index.html)

man sshd_config: [Русский](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sshd_config&category=5&russian=0) и [English](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)